# Reset Audio when I click on a link

Tags: javascript, html, audio

When I play an audio, pause the audio, click on the external link, then go back to the page where the audio is located, I want the audio to reset instead of leaving where I left off, but it leaves where I left off.

In my HTML5 page, I included this link before the closing body tag:
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">

HTML5:

```
<table id="multiplemp3">
    <tr>
       <th>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005876.LOFI.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005933.LOFI.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
<br>


<p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">More . . .</a></p>
<p><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">Return to Home Page</a></p>
```

JS:

```
/* allows user to play one mp3 at a time */

/* declare variables: get tag from html */
var audios = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

/* bind() is used for binding audio attribute and parameters of a function call, audio is the current audio element played( comes from the binding above), we compare each element in audios with this, and pause all those which are not matching. */

for (var i=0; i<audios.length;i++)  {
  audios[i].onplay = pauseAllAudios.bind(null, audios[i]); 
}

function pauseAllAudios(audio) {
    for(var i=0; i<audios.length;i++)
       if(audios[i]!=audio)  {
         audios[i].pause();    
       } else if (links.click() ) {
            audios[i].stop();    
      }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0eun4kcy/1/

Comment: I have tried opening the fiddle on Microsoft Edge and Firefox, and in both the audio is stopped and set to 0s when you go back.

Comment: When I test it on my local server it does not work.  But since I am using this library:  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"
maybe I have to test it on the server.  Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an event listener on the pause button, then automatically set the currentTime of the audio to zero. For example, if you have one audio element you could:

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");

audio.onpause = function() {
     audio.currentTime = 0;
};
```

This will reset audio file. The next time the user clicks the pause button, it will play from the beginning.